# In solidity if we use self destruct function , will the events emitted on blockchain will be deleted or only the data of blockchain will be erased?

Tags: solidity, selfdestruct

What actually happens after self destruct function is called ?

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.7;
contract PiggyBank{
    event Deposit(uint amount);
    event Withdraw(uint amount);
    receive() external payable {
        emit Deposit(msg.value);
    }
    address public owner = msg.sender;
    function withdraw() external{
        require(msg.sender ==owner ,"not owner");
        emit Withdraw(address(this).balance);
        selfdestruct(payable(msg.sender));
    }
}
```

In the above code if I destruct the contract then also I am able to access the functions of Smart Contract.What about the events I have emitted on Blockchain?

Answer (score 0):

event will not be deleted. when you call `selfdestruct(owner)`, byte code in that contract address is deleted but events are not stored in the byte code.

events are stored in the `logsBloom` which is stored in the header of each block.